# Where to place <start> and <end> tags in seq2seq translations?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, sequence, seq2seq

I went through a number of tutorials where the answer to my question was different.

So, for seq2seq model ( English to French translation ), I have `encoder_input_data` which has English phrases without `<start>` and `<stop>` tags.
I am confused with the `decoder_input_data` and `decoder_target_data`.

Currently, my data is organized in such a manner which results in nothing.

- `decoder_input_data` : Contains French phrases which have both `<start>` and `<stop>` tags.
- `decoder_target_data` : Contains French phrases which only have `<stop>` tag.

The [lesson from Google](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/nmt_with_attention) says that both the English and French phrases must have both the tags at the start and at the end. Also, I am getting no results.

> Should I put `<start>` and `<stop>` tags in the decoder's input? Or, should I include only the `<start>` in the decoder's input and only the `<stop>` tag in the decoder's target? What is the correct way to place these tags for NMT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put `<start>` tag in the decoder's input and put `<end>` tag in the decoder's target.

Please look at the following picture:

[image]

The `<start>` tag in the decoder's input is used to predict the first token in the decoder, and the `<end>` tag in the decoder's target is used to mark the ending in the decoder.

There is no need to take `<start>` tag in the target, because we have a clear initial starting in the decoder. Also, there is no need to take `<end>` tag in the input, because the ending is marked by the output not the input.

Moreover, there is some work that use `<start>` and `<end>` as the same mark. Actually, they are in the different place so they aren't conflicting.

Such as:

[image]

Comment: According to the 1st image we have to append the <end> tag in the encoder input data. Is is necessary?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal It isn't. I have seen many implementations which don't process the source text. Such as: https://github.com/IBM/pytorch-seq2seq/blob/master/seq2seq/dataset/fields.py